# Visual C# - Interfacing with a Bluetooth Dongle

Tags: bluetooth

how difficult would it be to interface with a Bluetooth Dongle (a generic one from eBay I'd say) from a Visual C# program? I've worked with Serial Ports before. Are serial ports the way forward in this case? Or should I be looking at a Bluetooth Adapter? I plan on using the Bluetooth Dongle because not all laptops may be shipped with a Bluetooth feature (some old ones) and so writing my C# program to always look for the Bluetooth Dongle and use it will ensure that it will always work.

Comment: It is not good idea to work with Bluetooth devices using Serial Ports. Better to use Bluetooth API. Nothing hard at all if you use any lib. 32feet is free one. Bluetooth Framework is commercial.

Comment: Hi @MikePetrichenko, thank you for your help. In order to use a Bluetooth API the PC would need to have an in-built Bluetooth adapter I think? Then if a dongle is used, it might still be used as a bluetooth adapter in the case that the PC does not have an in-built Bluetooth Adapter?

Comment: It does not matter/ You can use build-in if you have or USB dongle if needed. However if your device (PC or laptop) has build-in Bluetooth adapter and you prefer to connect USB one yo uneed to disable build-in Bluetooth. That is because no one Bluetooth driver supports more than 1 Bluetooth dongle. Also you should know that each Bluetooth driver has own API. That is why it is much simple to use third-party library that already provides support for all well-known Bluetooth drivers.

Comment: Hi Mike, I guess 32 feet would have a much higher probability of being compatible with the PC's in built Bluetooth hardware rather than an external USB dongle then.

Comment: It does not matter. 32feer and Bluetooth Framework tals to Bluetooth driver, not to hardware directly. So it does not matter how it is connected.

Comment: Well understood. And does Visual C# have a 'standard' way of communicating with the BLE or is a Framework always recommended to be used?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by standard way and depends on whaty you need. The common answer is - no, there is no build-in functions/classes for Bluetooth. For UWP apps the answer is yes, there is some API (classes) for that but with some (lot of) limitations. Those classes (from UWP) can be used in Desktop applications with some tricks. But again - there are lot of limitations. So for Desktop apps - yes, you better go with third-party libraries.